# How to use BeautifulSoup to validate that an XML is compatible with a given DTD?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, dtd

Suppose I have a bunch of .xmls which use a tag scheme defined in my own custom .DTD file.

How could I use BeautifulSoup4 to validate that a given .xml conforms to a given custom .DTD file (i.e. it doesn't have tags not defined in that .DTD)?  In particular I am using a `BeautifulSoup` class object, which takes a `file` as an argument and then parses the XML accordingly.

I have looked at these resources but they don't address how to directly solve this problem:

(1)http://lxml.de/validation.html

(2)http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.DTD-class.html

(3)http://lxml.de/api/index.html

Comment: The instance of `BeautifulSoup` uses `lxml` as its XML parser.

Comment: Why can't you use the `lxml` library?

Comment: That would require re-writing the class I think (it extends the `BeautifulSoup`).